# how to get post tags in mvc actionresult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this ViewModel:

```
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int City { get; set; }
```

and in View ,Users can Add some tage like as this :

```
book,story,c#,...
```

All tags in view in `Li` in `UL`.
How can I get All tag value in ActionResult .
I searched on Google but cant find any result.

I think add a `List` to the Model and all li names are same ? do that right ?

My html like this :

```
    <li class="tag-item">one</li>
<li class="tag-item">two</li>
<li class="tag-item">three</li>
```

**Updated:**
I use this Script to add Tags to `UL` :

```
    $("#txttag").keydown(function (e) {
var value = $(this).val();
if (value.length >0 && e.which==13)
{
    var markup = "<li class='tag-item'> @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Tags)" + value + "<a class='tag-close'>X</a></li>";
    $("#taglist").append(markup);
    $(this).val('');

}
});
```

but shows `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Tags)` in Li value ,

Comment: You need to post the values by using a `form`.  Look up how to submit a form to an ActionResult

Comment: @Coulton can you tell me , how do this ? can you post your answer ?

Comment: It is literally the basis of ASP.NET MVC.  There are zillions of articles out there.  Type "submit form in asp.net mvc" into Google

Comment: Instead of `<li>` elements, you need a `form` and `input` tags.

Comment: can you post an answer?

Comment: Please post the HTML that you have so far :)

Comment: Do you want to post the values to your actionresult?

Comment: @Coulton Yes , I want in actionresult get all li value

Comment: or do an ajax post back and the data can come from a jquery scrape of the text from the `li` tags.

Comment: @ps2goat , I don't want use ajax call ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to post the values to the action result.  Add the list to your model:

```
public string Title { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public int City { get; set; }
public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
```

Change the Javascript code to include the values in hidden `input` fields:

```
var markup = "<li class='tag-item'><input type='hidden' name='Tags' value='" + value  + "' />" + value + "<a class='tag-close'>X</a></li>";
```

Your code would not be setting the `value=""` parameter of the hidden fields, but with the above code it will.

Comment: li tags is dynamic by jquery . for example , i have a textbox when user enter key down i add a `li` tag and append it to `ul` .   I use this :     `var markup = "<li class='tag-item'> @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Tags)" + value + "<a class='tag-close'>X</a></li>";
        $("#taglist").append(markup);`

Comment: ok, you need to replace the @Html.HiddenFor() in your javascript to pure Html code I think?  I have updated my answer.